# SSD I/O slows down system

Tags: windows, hard-drive, memory, ssd, io

My HDD was getting full, so I added a new SSD and tried moving files to it. For some reason, this bogs down the whole system to the point where it's not usable. This never happened with HDDs when copying/moving files from one (spinning) HDD to another. Is this an issue specific to SSDs? How can I prevent simple I/O operations from completely bogging down the system?

The OS is Windows 7. I didn't discover any processes using up excessive resources and I can also confirm that AHCI mode is selected in BIOS.

Comment: Have a look at the ressource monitor, especially the queue length of your volumes.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check "System" event log for some disk errors. There are probably some, which deny normal work of some disk services like windows search, leading to lags of whole OS